# optional arguments with math.pi

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently teaching myself how to use functions and their respective parameters. I need my secondary function to accept pi as an argument then convert it to a string that gets returned to my main function and printed. Can anyone please explain why my code isn't running?

```
import math


def pi_string(x = math.pi):
  y = str(x)
  return y


def main():
  print(pi_string())
```

Comment: just call `main()` and it should print. You have to call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you don't invoke your main function, add this code below to call the main function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Always something so obvious - thank you good sir! will accept your answer as soon as it lets me